# How to find the most optimum value for a function argument given a desired answer in R?

Tags: r, function, math, linear-algebra, equation

I was wondering how to find the most precise value for `t` given that I want the answer of the entire function call below become `3` in R?

```
if(!require(BayesFactor)){install.packages('BayesFactor')} ; library(BayesFactor)

# 3 = function call below:
unname(ttest.tstat( t, 20, 20, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]])
```

Comment: have a look at `optim`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using optim. `par` is the value of t that gets you closest to 3. The other methods may get you even closer, but that is outside my wheel house.

```
library(BayesFactor)

f1 <- function(t){
  abs(ttest.tstat( t, 20, 20, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]]-3)
}

f2 <- function(t){
  ttest.tstat( t, 20, 20, rscale = sqrt(2)/2, simple = TRUE)[[1]]
}

optim(par=-1, fn = f1)

#$par
#[1] -2.440637
#
#$value
#[1] 1.140988e-07
#
#$counts
#function gradient 
#      56       NA 
#
#$convergence
#[1] 0
# 
#$message
#NULL
```

#### Edit:

Two other ways to optimize the value of `t` taking into account the warning that Nelder-Mead is unreliable for one-dimensional optimization. The warning just means that there are/is better methods to optimize a univariate function.

```
optim(par=-1, fn = f1, method="Brent", lower = -100, upper=100)
optimize(f1, interval = c(-100,100))
```

Comment: Thanks, but why I get the following warning: `Warning message:
In optim(par = -1, fn = f1) :
  one-dimensional optimization by Nelder-Mead is unreliable:
use "Brent" or optimize() directly`

Comment: f2 lets you check the parameter in your original function. You can disregard it